# unix shell script not working gives me error

Tags: macos, unix

what is wrong with my code this is it -

```
export -P ttiUsername="Username: " || ^
```

i get an error about command ^ and the -p 
here is my error

```
/Users/michaelgray/Desktop/ToontownWorld/ToontownInfiniteRetro/start_game.sh: line 3: export: -P: invalid option
export: usage: export [-nf] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
/Users/michaelgray/Desktop/ToontownWorld/ToontownInfiniteRetro/start_game.sh: line 3: ^: command not found
```

edit: i lowercased the p but it doesnt prompt u to enter username like it should

Comment: Why should this "prompt for a username"?

Comment: Its a game and it the database needs a username to start and so we ask them to enter a username to put into the database

Comment: Sure, I guessed that much. But that is not a reason why your code line should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is this line:

```
export -P ttiUsername="Username: " || ^
```

It's wrong because `export` doesn't read data, `-P` is not a valid option, and `^` is not a valid command. None of it makes sense if the goal is to read data.

To read data from the user, use `read`:

```
read -p "Username: " ttiUsername
echo "You wrote: $ttiUsername"
```

Comment: @Mgracer There should be a tick mark next to the answer